# Постоянное подключение на PHP со свойствами LongPolling и WebSocket

Tags: php, websocket, long-poll

LongPolling работает так, что клиент подключается к серверу по протоколу http(s) и зависает, пока сервер не ответит. После этого создается новое подключение. Это подключение происходит абсолютно стандартным образом с отправкой всех заголовков и cookie. Для каждого такого подключения апач (или другой сервер) создает изолированный процесс.

WebSocket в свою очередь подключается к специальному серверу по отдельному протоколу ws(s). Выходит, что есть всего один процесс, в котором должна проходить авторизация, и велика вероятность утечек памяти. Но преимущества этого подхода в том, что есть постоянное подключение, что обеспечивает моментальную реакцию на события. Помимо прочего, в случае работы с WS не обязательно хранить сообщения где-то в БД, чтобы ничего не было потеряно при переподключении.

Вопрос вот в чем: есть ли что-то среднее между LP и WS?

- Работает по протоколу http(s) со всеми плюшками (headers и cookies)
- Можно написать простой PHP скрипт, который будет запускаться по запросу и обрабатывать все эти подключения, а не пилить полноценный WS сервер, который нужно будет еще мониторить и следить за тем, чтобы он правильно работал. (P.S. Я в проекте единственный разработчик/дизайнер/верстальщик/сис.админ/другое слово, поэтому не хочется добавлять себе еще хлопот)
- Для каждого подключения спаунит отдельный процесс, изолированный от других подключений
- Имеет постоянное подключение. И чтобы можно было отправлять сообщения хотя бы в одну сторону (сервер => клиент)

---

#### Подробнее о том, в чем собственно проблема.

В проекте используется framework Yii2 с местной системой авторизации и со всеми его плюшками. Описанный мною подход позволил бы мне аутентифицировать пользователя встроенными в framework методами, а саму логику внедрить в action контроллера.

В противном случае мне нужно будет написать отдельный сервер или использовать готовое решение и как-то интегрировать его с фреймворком.

Смотрел в строну [Workerman](https://github.com/walkor/Workerman). Опять же возникает вопросы аутентификации, поддержки сервера в рабочем состоянии при утечках и крашах (supervisord?), перезапуска при деплое

> Если я где-то заблуждаюсь, тыкните, пожалуйста, пальцем.

Comment: Как-то грустно. Неужели ни у кого даже мыслей на этот счет нет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Достойных альтернатив для WebSocket в наше время считайте что нет. Или WebSocket, или всевозможные костыли. Если без костылей, то...

Первое, что нужно сделать: [настроить nginx для передачи WebSocket соединений дальше по цепочке](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/websocket.html). Так, все ваши клиенты будут работать с nginx, а не напрямую с вашими другими про­граммами. Сохраняются и используются все достоинства nginx. Не нужно использовать выде­ленный порт. Не нужно настраивать HTTPS дважды. Не нужно перезапускать какие-то другие про­граммы после обновления сертификатов Let's Encrypt.

Настройка делается в четыре строчки:

```
location /mywsapp {
    proxy_pass http://mywsbackend;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

Дальше, нужна альтернатива самостоятельной обработке входящих соединений WebSocket. Такая программа будет брать на себя обработку входящих WS соединений во всей их слож­ности, оставляя вам лишь обработку входящих сообщений и отправку исходящих.

#### websocketd

Например, программа [websocketd](https://github.com/joewalnes/websocketd) работает как inetd, только для процессов. При новом соеди­нении запускается ваша программа, которой нужно читать стан­дартный вход и писать в стан­дартный выход. Можно не читать, только писать. [Пример использования в другом ответе.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765524/201364)

```
<?php
while ($name = fgets(STDIN)) {
    echo "Hello $name!\n";
}
```

Всевозможные заголовки, которые отправляет ваш клиент, [доступны через переменные окру­жения](https://github.com/joewalnes/websocketd/wiki/Environment-variables). Например, куки видны в `$_ENV['HTTP_COOKIE']` и так далее.

Вашим требованиям в части запуска процесса по факту подключения этот подход соответ­ствует. Есть недостатки: если вам повезёт вырасти до сотен или тысяч одномоментных под­ключений, то это будет означать сотни и тысячи висящих в памяти процессов PHP. Впрочем, об этом можно будет подумать потом.

Кроме ограничений по памяти, постоянно работающие процессы PHP создают ещё одну проблему: если вам захочется обновить их логику, то вам потребуется механизм отключения всех таких процессов.

#### nchan

Если забыть про некоторые требования, то модуль [nchan](https://github.com/slact/nchan) для nginx может ещё больше аб­стра­гировать работу с сообщениями. Для каждого подключающегося клиента вы выделяете какой-то длинный и секретный ID (что-то типа номера почтового ящика), по которому тот подключается к nchan и ждёт сообщения. Вы, со своей стороны, по этому же ID отправляете сообщения по простому HTTP. Если у вас появится больше одного сервера, то забирать сообщения nchan может из Redis.

Установка проще не может быть:

```
sudo apt install libnginx-mod-nchan
```

[Пример конфигурации.](https://github.com/slact/nchan#getting-started)

Недостатки: увеличенная сложность конфигурации nginx и всей архитектуры системы, необходимость хранить идентификаторы клиентов за пределами `$_SESSION`.

Достоинства: не нужно для каждого соединения держать процесс PHP.

---

Список будет пополняться.

Comment: Я нашел для себя такой инструмент, как EventSourcing. Полностью совместим с http, передает все куки. Работает точно, как обычный http запрос, но лучше. В связке с RabbitMQ дает неплохие результаты. У меня на компе... На production сервере не все так радужно. По какой-то причине после определенного времени соединение прерывается с ошибкой `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR`. После нескольких таких переподключений сервер может лечь совсем. Nginx начнет выдавать ошибку 50*, а SSH не пускает совсем. Очень похоже на утечки памяти. Сижу, мониторю память top'ом

Comment: В логах обычно пишут кого oomkiller прибил за память.

Comment: Очень понравился websocketd с его простотой использования. Спасибо большое. Хотя, ответ `EventSourcing` больше соответствует вопросу. Но Вы "открыли мне глаза". За что я Вам очень благодарен)