# NGINX: раздача дописываемого файла

Tags: nginx, http, long-poll

В моем приложении есть файл, который по сути напоминает лог т.е. постоянно дописывается. Хочу использовать хедер Range для как альтернативу long polling и вебсокетам для чтения дополняющегося файла, так как на реализацию этих технологий нужно время, тем более с учетом использования С++. Насколько эффективно NGINX справится с такой задачей, возможно будут проблемы при работе с дополняющимися файлами? И какие параметры будут оптимальными для реализации этого подхода? Может быть нужно использовать directio в приложении и NGINX для оптимизации? Или стоит вообще отказаться от этой идеи?...
Сервер на базе linux, файловая система ext4. Размер файла не превышает 100МБ(одновременно запись идет в один файл, потом создается новый).

PS: В файл придется писать в любом случае и разбивка на мелкие файлы не связана с реализацией этого подхода.

Comment: Если приложение однажды уже скачало файл, то как ему скачать потом только то, что добавилось? Может лучше БД для такого лога использовать?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov вполне может, все нужные фичи для этого есть в HTTP, и nginx их подерживает

Comment: @Alexander, мое упущение. Читаем весь файл, записываем сколько байт считали, через опр. интервал запрашиваем файл с `Range: bytes=n-`. Добавляем к n кол-во полученных байт, и так "дополучаем" файл по мере его дополнения. Да тут именно быстро отдавать ответы нужно, а не ждать БД. Просто боюсь что в опр. момент что-то пойдет не так при конкурентном чтении и записи файла.

Comment: @Fixturessd, а если partial request получится на два файла ("одновременно запись идет в один файл, потом создается новый")? С базой, все же, проще.

Comment: @Alexander, логика приложения такова, что в любом случае придется каждую минуту создавать новый файл и данные между файлами не связаны. Если бы задача стояла по другому, то можно использовать один большой файл. С базой действительно проще, но... нужна максимальная производительность

Comment: Можно подумать с файлами у вас будет максимальная производительность! С чего вы решили? Как раз таки базы данных оптимизированы чтобы давать максимальную производительность в таких случаях: хотя бы потому что хранят горячие данные в памяти. Файловая система тоже что-то такое делает, но в отличии от БД - никаких гарантий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не имеет смысла изобретать велосипед так как для nginx уже есть модуль для работы с вебсокетами, который берет всю сложную работу на себя. Вам остается только передавать сообщения для доставки в nginx. Устанавливается на раз:

```
sudo apt install libnginx-mod-nchan
```

[Настройка тоже ничего сложного не представляет.](https://github.com/slact/nchan#getting-started) Может работать через Redis в конфигурации с множеством серверов.

Если вы по какой-то причине не можете использовать этот модуль, то опять же стоит изобретать очередную БД на коленке. На серьёзных нагрузках файлы на диске никогда не заменят настоящую БД, будь это MySQL или что. Хотя бы потому что типичная БД может гарантировать что горячие данные будут в оперативке, тогда как дисковый кеш вообще ничего не гарантирует. Это очень легко проверить простым бенчмарком.

---

Из альтернатив можно рассмотреть, например, [websocketd](https://github.com/joewalnes/websocketd). Эта программа, очень близкая по сути inetd, существует отдельно от nginx. Вам нужно лишь [перенаправить WS соединения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/731951/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-longpolling-%D0%B8-websocket/758037) на неё, что очень просто.

```
location /mywsapp {
    proxy_pass http://mywsbackend;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

В простейшем виде, без nginx, программа, которая будет читать из файла новый строки и передавать их по WebSocket будет выглядеть так: (`tail.sh`)

```
#!/bin/bash
tail -q -n0 -F /tmp/websocketdata.txt
```

Страница, которая читает данные, выглядит так: (`index.html`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="data"></div>
<script>
var container = document.getElementById('data');

var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/');
ws.onmessage = function(event) {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.textContent = event.data;
  container.insertBefore(p, container.firstChild);
};
</script>
```

Если оба файла в одном каталоге, то запускаем:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000 &
./websocketd --port=8080 ./tail.sh &
```

Открываем в браузере http://127.0.0.1:8000/ и в соседней консоли пишем в файл:

```
tee -a /tmp/websocketdata.txt
```

Печатаем текст и смотрим как он появляется в окне браузера в тот же миг.

Это читающей программе будут доступны всевозможные переменные как если бы она работала CGI в окружении, например `QUERY_STRING` и другие. Без необходимости  их проверять можно сделать даже так, убрав прослойку из bash:

```
./websocketd --port=8080 tail -q -n0 -F /tmp/websocketdata.txt
```

Чтобы не усложнять программу для чтения файлов можно проверять доступ к подключению через WebSocket на стороне nginx используя [директиву auth_request](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html).